# Error al crear TRIGGER en mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy intentando crear un TRIGGER para que cuando se inserte un employee se verifique si esta en nulo el email y si lo esta pues que inserte una row en la tabla advertencias, pero cuando ejecuto la sentencia me da el error:

> [Start] Executing MySQL query... Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
> CREATE TRIGGER advertaisment  BEFORE INSERT ON employees FOR ...' at
> line 1 [Done] Finished MySQL query.

```
use classicmodels;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER advertaisment 
BEFORE INSERT ON employees
FOR EACH STATEMENT 
BEGIN
IF(NEW.email = '' OR NEW.email IS NULL) THEN
INSERT INTO advertencias
    SET id = 0,
    codigo = NEW.employeenumber,
    mensaje = 'Email en empleado vacio proveniente de employees',
    accion = 'insert',
    nombre_tabla = 'employees',
    usuario = CURRENT_USER(),
    fecha = NOW();
END IF;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Si vas a colocar código, hazlo de preferencia en texto ya que eso facilita la ayuda aparte de que el código en imagen no es bien recibido. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta en cualquier momento.

Comment: ya lo he cambiado
gracias por la ayuda

Comment: En Mariadb, una parte de la sintaxis del trigger es `FOR EACH ROW`, te paso el enlace de la documentación de la sintaxis [CREATE TRIGGER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-trigger/)

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora mismo la veo